# Incluir JLabel en JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy intentando mostrar un JLabel en un JPanel, pero no se me muestra. No sé por qué será

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DialogoCancion extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel titulo;
    private JLabel interprete;
    private JLabel duracion;
    private JButton añadir;
    private JButton cancelar;

    public DialogoCancion(){
        super("Añadir Cancion");
        setBounds(150, 80, 250, 150);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        titulo = new JLabel("Titulo");
        interprete = new JLabel ("Interprete");
        duracion = new JLabel ("Duracion");
        añadir = new JButton ("Añadir");
        cancelar = new JButton ("Cancelar");

        titulo.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 80);
        panel.add(titulo);
        panel.add(interprete);
        panel.add(duracion);
        panel.add(añadir);
        panel.add(cancelar);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Quiero que se vea `titulo`, pero no me sale nada.

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, presente una forma distinta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias agregar al final de tu codigo

```
add(panel);
setVisible(true);
```

Ya que tu clase extiende de un `JFrame` cuando crees la instancia de tu clase podras verlo pero mientras no agregues el panel a tu `JFrame` no se vera nada.

Answer (score 0):

te falta el add(panel) ya que usas extends jframe

pero si no usarias extends JFrame y lo invocaras como Objeto seria:

asi :nota que instacie Jframe como un objeto y agregue el panel al frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DialogoCancion  {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel titulo;
private JLabel interprete;
private JLabel duracion;
private JButton añadir;
private JButton cancelar;

public DialogoCancion(){
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(150, 80, 250, 150);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    titulo = new JLabel("Titulo");
    interprete = new JLabel ("Interprete");
    duracion = new JLabel ("Duracion");
    añadir = new JButton ("Añadir");
    cancelar = new JButton ("Cancelar");

    titulo.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 80);
    panel.add(titulo);
    panel.add(interprete);
    panel.add(duracion);
    panel.add(añadir);
    panel.add(cancelar);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    DialogoCancion dc=new DialogoCancion();
}
}
```

aca te dejo un screenshot que demuestra la funcionalidad
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Encontré algunos inconvenientes. No tenias un método main. No es necesario el metodo main en la clase DialogoCancion, pero como no incluiste las demas clases o no se si es la unica que utilizas, le agregue. La idea es para que sea funcional tu clase y puedas ver el resultado. 
No habías colocado un add al panel como también tu layer como BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) para que aparezcan tus elementos uno debajo del otro.

```
import javax.swing.*;
    public class DialogoCancion extends JFrame {
        private JPanel panel;
        private JLabel titulo;
        private JLabel interprete;
        private JLabel duracion;
        private JButton añadir;
        private JButton cancelar;

        public DialogoCancion(){
            super("Añadir Cancion");
            setBounds(150, 80, 250, 150);
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            titulo = new JLabel("Titulo");
            interprete = new JLabel ("Interprete");
            duracion = new JLabel ("Duracion");
            añadir = new JButton ("Añadir");
            cancelar = new JButton ("Cancelar");

            titulo.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 80);
            panel.add(titulo);
            panel.add(interprete);
            panel.add(duracion);
            panel.add(añadir);
            panel.add(cancelar);

            add(panel);

            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            DialogoCancion frame = new DialogoCancion();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que no este en el metodo main en el codigo que el proporciona no dice que no esta. Porque es una clase, puede tener una clase main aparte. Saludos!

Comment: @sioesi Ya se que puede tener el método mail en otra clase. Pero no se si utiliza otra clase o no. No menciona eso. Entonces por esa razón le incluí para que pueda ver que funciona con la clase que proporciona. Cualquier cosa puede modificar a su antojo. Voy a incluir esa parte en la respuesta porque podría dar confusión.